# Using Sed multiple search pattern printing specific lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed

SED command usage multiple pattern

I am using the sed command to search  for multiple patterns.
The command works and print the lines when it find matches 
However I need to do 2 things ( here is the command I use)

```
  sed -r '/pattern1|pattern2/!d' filename
```

A - Print the line containing the first pattern 
     then print not only the line matching the second pattern 
     but  print the number of lines below it. I like to specify
     the number of lines below second pattern search .

B - I need to print first pattern and then  only a certain number of lines below
      the 2nd pattern but omit the line containing the search pattern

In short, I need to  control specify the number of lines below 
my second serach pattern and omit the line containing the serach patetrn as well if 
I decide to do so

```
Hostname1

section1 
a

section2
a
c 
d

Hostname2

section1 
a

section2
x
y
d
```

desired Output

```
hostname1
section2
a
c 

hostname2
section2
x
y
```

Comment: You need to better describe what you're trying to do. Your sample output doesn't tell us what your search patterns are for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create test file 
(
cat << EOF
Hostname1

section1
a

section2
a
c
d

Hostname2

section1
a

section2
x
y
d
EOF
) > filename

# transformation
cat filename  | grep -v "^ *$" | sed -e "s/\(Hostname\)/==\1/g" |  sed -e "s/\(section\)/=\1/g" | tr '\n' '|' | tr '=' '\n' |  sed -r '/Hostname1|Hostname2|section2/!d' | cut -d"|" -f-3 | tr '|' '\n' | grep -v "^ *$" | sed -e "s/\(Hostname\)/\n\1/g"
```

## explications

```
# etape 1 : transforme each section to on ligne, with a dilimiter "|" :
cat filename  | grep -v "^ *$" | sed -e "s/\(Hostname\)/==\1/g" |  sed -e "s/\(section\)/=\1/g" | tr '\n' '|' | tr '=' '\n' 
#Hostname1|
#section1|a|
#section2|a|c|d|
#
#Hostname2|
#section1|a|
#section2|x|y|d|

# etape 2 : cut n+1 fild  ( cut -d"|" -f-3 ) :
cat filename |  cat filename  | grep -v "^ *$" | sed -e "s/\(Hostname\)/==\1/g" |  sed -e "s/\(section\)/=\1/g" | tr '\n' '|' | tr '=' '\n' |  sed -r '/Hostname1|Hostname2|section2/!d' | cut -d"|" -f-3
#Hostname1|
#section2|a|c
#Hostname2|
#section2|x|y

#etape 3 : transfomation to wanted format :
cat filename |  cat filename  | grep -v "^ *$" | sed -e "s/\(Hostname\)/==\1/g" |  sed -e "s/\(section\)/=\1/g" | tr '\n' '|' | tr '=' '\n' |  sed -r '/Hostname1|Hostname2|section2/!d' | cut -d"|" -f-3 | tr '|' '\n' | grep -v "^ *$" | sed -e "s/\(Hostname\)/\n\1/g"
#Hostname1
#section2
#a
#c
#
#Hostname2
#section2
#x
#y
```